# Facing connection issue while running copy in Vertica

Tags: parsing, connection, vertica

When I am running my COPY script , below error comes:
Unable to report error to server:Connection I/O error

This is not just failing but also node goes down with it.

Has anyone ever come across any such issue ?
In my copy i am using Fjsonparser.
The same script was running fine until today ,today I did 3 reruns all the time query failed and node went down. could there be any data issue ? If yes , what particularly I should be looking for in json that i am trying to copy.

Comment: Has the json file format changed? Can you trigger the error with just two or three rows/records  of the json file? And, if yes, can you post both the COPY command and the offending small json file? On another note: does the json file come without record delimiters?

Comment: Hey ! no the format of the file is still the same.You know i am not allowed by dba to run any test until I am sure it will run successfully because copy not just fails but also the node goes down with it which affects other applications. I checked for any null values like any special characters or empty lines but the file look cleans.The same copy command has been working for a month all of a sudden it has started failing. Any idea what i should be looking particularly inside the file , cause it has around 200k records.

Comment: Put the same on a test system. Make the input file smaller and smaller, until you have just enough to trigger the error. Please share the exact copy command you're using, and the table's ddl, using `SELECT EXPORT_OBJECTS('','<your_schema>.<your_table>',FALSE)` . And if you have  a small enough offfending JSON file, the file itself. What to look for? Missing record delimiters (they are not needed in JSON format, but help for reading) can sometimes trigger problems for very big files.

Comment: @marcothesane , I have come to know that one of the column in the json has size bigger than the size defined in the table.This is the column within json array. But then I think ,all such records should be directed to rejected data right instead of crashing the node. Sorry I am not allowed to post code or file here. And thanks for helping me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to your explanation, I can now suggest a remedy:

Take a deviation, by using a *flex table* , and :

```
CREATE FLEX TABLE my_flex_test();
COPY my_flex_test FROM '/your/data/directory/your_small_sample_file.json' 
  PARSER fjsonparser(<your_original_parameters>);
```

This creates a two-column table:

```
CREATE TABLE my_flex_test (
  __identity__ BIGINT                NOT NULL
, __raw__      LONGVARBINARY(130000) NOT NULL
)
;
```

Now, you can have Vertica guess types and sizes :

```
SELECT COMPUTE_FLEXTABLE_KEYS('my_flex_test');
```

And then (this is a very small example of mine):

```
SELECT * FROM my_flex_test_keys;
 key_name | frequency | data_type_guess 
----------+-----------+-----------------
 recordid |         2 | Varchar(40)
 fare     |         2 | Numeric(6,3)
```

Use the `data_type_guess` suggestions to modify your table columns .

Comment: I don't understand the issue very well ,however it got resolved ,the file got loaded when i defined one of the not null column of the table as nullable . Usually this type of issue is  handled by REJECTED DATA  but in this case it wasn't.  For other files REJECTED DATA used to simply reject such null records.